# Suppressing sparks when attaching buck converter to battery

Tags: dc-dc-converter

i have bought a cheap DC/DC converter (24v to 19v, 15A, [link](http://www.current-logic.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=5&products_id=319)). When i attach a 24v battery pack to the converter input i get sparks. Is there any way to suppress these sparks when i attach the converter?

Edit: I want to power a Intel NUC mini computer with the converter. My idea was to use a relay to turn the dcdc output on and off. Wouldn't the sparks damage the relay contacts or weld them ?

Comment: Sparks are caused by high inrush current, probably to load the input caps of your DCDC. They are not harmful per se, but of course depending on the operating environment they can pose a threat. Can you share the part number of your DCDC, and the load conditions you will be using it for? Also, understanding why you need to suppress them is key.

Comment: Why do you want to suppress the spark?  You haven't given any reason to not just let them happen.

Comment: Why suppress them? sparks are **cool!**

Comment: A suitable NTC in series would solve that, if you can spare some efficiency.

Comment: What if I told you there's a spark almost every time you switch on/off the light in your house. Or the toaster or the hairdryer. Unless you listen to an AM radio all day you would probably never notice.

Comment: @VladimirCravero here is a link to the converter [DCDC link](http://www.current-logic.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=5&products_id=319) I want to power a Intel NUC mini computer with the converter. My idea was to use a relay to turn the dcdc output on and off. Wouldn't the sparks damage the relay contacts or weld them ?

Comment: You want to control the power connection with a relay. If you are to change the switching element to a MOSFET, then you can use one of the circuit detailed by Andy Aka and implement the switching by controlling the gate of the MOSFET. Done properly with a MOSFET, there will be a some loss of efficiency but a potential improvement in reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to suppress these sparks when i attach the converter?

This is caused by inrush current and, for many devices like this can be several tens or even hundreds of amps i.e. much more than the normal full-load running input current. It can be particularly bad on on-line SMPS units and a lot of them use a negative temperature coefficient thermistor to reduce this transient effect.

The thermistor has an initially high resistance when cold thus lowering inrush current but, as it warms over the period of a few seconds, its resistance drops significantly. However, it represents a loss in efficiency even when warm so some circuits have evolved to use a MOSFET to control the inrush: -

[image]

Q1 initially does not switch on when power is applied due to the capacitor C1. That capacitor gradually (over a second or so) charges and as it does so the MOSFET is turned on gradually thus alleviating the inrush problem.

Here's another example with values: -

[image]

Image stolen from [here](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1225624) and here's a version with a little more sophistication: -

[image]

The extra transistor guarantees that the current cannot rise above a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the sparks, but not without some tradeoff.

The sparks are caused by the very low impedance of the battery pack charging up the input capacitor in the inverter.  Having the battery pack have low impedance is a good thing, and so is the converter having a some local low-impedance energy storage.

One way to reduce the spark is to put some impedance in series with the battery.  For example, take one of the leads and wrap it around a iron bolt a few times.  That adds series inductance, which reduces the sharp increase in current caused by the battery being abruptly connected to the capacitor.

However, as said before, having a low impedance battery is a good thing.  You therefore have a tradeoff between adding enough series inductance to reduce the spark, versus adding too much series inductance to so that the converter doesn't operate properly, particularly in response to a sudden spike in required output power.

You could short out the inductor with a second switch a few 100 ms after the first switch is closed, but this is getting silly unless there is a really good reason you need to avoid the spark.

Answer (score -1):

Use an inline switch in the cable.

Comment: That would not suppress the sparks, it would only hide them.

Comment: I think hiding them would be enough for most applications, the hard metal contacts of a suitable switch will survive better than a battery terminal or connector.  To suppress them you would need to have a soft start circuit that has minimal capacitance at the input and only starts to draw current progressively after the input is live to charge up the ripple caps of the main converter.  A good thing in [Ex] environments but overkill otherwise.